# Guice 3.0 @ScopeSession User object not invalidate on session timeout

Tags: struts2, guice, session-timeout, inject

I have a class :

```
@SessionScoped
public class LoggedUser {
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

that I use to keep track if a user is logged in my application.

In my Struts2 application I have a Interceptor to check if the user is logged, if not he's forwarded to the login page.

```
public class LoggedUserInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2822434409188961460L;

    @Inject
    private LoggedUser loggedUser;

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception { 
        if(loggedUser==null || !loggedUser.isLogged()){
            return "login";
        }
        return invocation.invoke();
    }

}
```

The problem occur when the session timeout.  The object LoggdeUser is never null or deleted.  I have always the last instance.

I added A session listener.

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SessionListener.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        logger.info("sessionCreated = " + event.getSession().getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        logger.info("sessionDestroyed = " + event.getSession().getId());
    }

}
```

I see that sessionDestroyed is called, but when I enter again in my Interceptor.. LoggedUser is never recreated for a new session.

why ?

my Struts2 Action for the login is this

```
public class LoginUserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<LoggedUser>, ServletRequestAware {
    ...
    @Inject
    private LoggedUser loggedUser;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        ...
        loggerUser.setLoggedTime(now);
        ...
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

I add that too in web.xml

```
session-config
    session-timeout 2 /session-timeout
    /session-config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to do that is finally to put the token in the session at the login and check it with an Interceptor

```
@Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

        loggedUser = (LoggedUser) invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().get(LoggedUser.SESSIONTOKEN);

        if(loggedUser==null || !loggedUser.isLogged()){
            logger.info("loggedUser not present in session");
            return "login";
        }

        return invocation.invoke();
    }
```

in the Action

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(LoggedUser.SESSIONTOKEN, loggedUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Struts2, but my guess is that the interceptor's scope is wider than session scope. In other words, the interceptor instance is kept around longer than the session. Guice can't and won't set an injected field to `null` when the session ends, nor will it ever re-inject an object automatically.

What you need to do if you use an object with a shorter lifecycle inside an object with a longer lifecycle (such as a `RequestScoped` object inside a `SessionScoped` object or a `SessionScoped` object inside a singleton) is inject a `Provider` for the shorter lived object.

In your case, I think this is probably what you need:

```
public class LoggedUserInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2822434409188961460L;

    @Inject
    private Provider<LoggedUser> loggedUserProvider;

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        LoggedUser loggedUser = loggedUserProvider.get();
        if(loggedUser==null || !loggedUser.isLogged()){
            return "login";
        }
        return invocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your solution.  THe problem is that the object is never unvalidated from the session.  So the user is always connected event when the session is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know guice but the session is available to the interceptor and can be made readily available to the action via SessionAware :

ActionInvocation provides access to the session. The following is part of a "Authentication" interceptor. If there is not a "User" object then Action.LOGIN is returned.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    Map session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    appLayer.User user = (appLayer.User) session.get("User");
    if (user == null){
        return Action.LOGIN;
    }
    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

I only place the user object on the session when the user logs in.

In the login action I place the user object on the session:

```
public class Login extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
  private Map<String, Object> session;
  private String userName;
  private String password;

  public String execute() {
    //use DB authentication once this works
    //if ("ken".equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && "ken".equalsIgnoreCase(password)){
    try {
        User user = new User(userName, password);
        session.put("User", user);
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was an exception" + e.getMessage());
        return ActionSupport.LOGIN;
    }
  } 

  public void validate() {
    String user = this.getUserName();
    String pass = this.getPassword();
    //This block is a bit redundant but I couldn't figure out how
    //to get just the hibernate part to report an exception on Username/pass
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(this.getUserName()) && !StringUtils.isBlank(this.getPassword())) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver").newInstance();
            String url = "jdbc:as400://192.168.1.14";
            DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass).close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addFieldError("login.error.authenticate", "Bad Username / Password");
        }
      }
      if (StringUtils.isBlank(getUserName())) {
        addFieldError("login.error.name", "Missing User Name");
      }
      if (StringUtils.isBlank(getPassword())) {
        addFieldError("login.error.password", "Missing Password");
      }
    //else both are blank don't report an error at this time
  }

  ... getters/setters....
  }//end class
```

If I remember correctly this comes from at least in part from "Struts2 in Action". Anyways I'm a big believer in DI but since the Session is pretty accessible from the interceptors and the action I don't bother.

Comment: If I'm not able to get it works with DI, I'll have the session by hand like the old time.. but this time I really want to know what I missed to make this works.

Comment: I do the same... can you add the imports for your annotation @Inject? S2 has an @Inject too.